# Flex items and line breaks

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this layout ([check on codepen](https://codepen.io/fox_hover/pen/9a2b17e62051cd39e18dd56e7574af7c)) with this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="line-up">

  <!--line up list-->
  <ul class="line-up__list">

    <!--line-up item-->
    <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Alva Noto Unieqav (Live)"><strong>Alva Noto Unieqav</strong>(Live)</a></li>

    <!--line-up item-->
    <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Anetha"><strong>Anetha</strong></a></li>

    <!--line-up item-->
    <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Antigone &amp; Shlømo présentent Luxor (Live) "><strong>Antigone &amp; Shlømo</strong>présentent<strong>Luxor</strong>(Live)</a></li>

    <!--line-up item-->
    <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Bonaventure"><strong>Bonaventure</strong></a></li>

    <!--line-up item-->
    <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Ciel"><strong>Ciel</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line-up {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e8c0a0;
}

.line-up__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  list-style-type: none;
}

.line-up__item {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 3px;

  line-height: 1.45;

  //decoration element
  &:after {
    margin-left: 3px;

    font: {
      size: 25px;
    }

    content: '•';
  }

  &:last-child {

    &:after {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

//line up links styles
a.line-up__link {

  //bigger item styles
  strong {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 3px;

    font: {
      size: 19px;
    }

    &:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line-up {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e8c0a0;
}

.line-up__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.line-up__item {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 3px;
  line-height: 1.45;
}

.line-up__item:after {
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: 25px;
  content: '•';
}

.line-up__item:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}

a.line-up__link strong {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
  font-size: 19px;
}

a.line-up__link strong:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-up">

  <!--line up list-->
  <ul class="line-up__list">

    <!--line-up item-->
    <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Alva Noto Unieqav (Live)"><strong>Alva Noto Unieqav</strong>(Live)</a></li>

    <!--line-up item-->
    <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Anetha"><strong>Anetha</strong></a></li>

    <!--line-up item-->
    <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Antigone &amp; Shlømo présentent Luxor (Live) "><strong>Antigone &amp; Shlømo</strong>présentent<strong>Luxor</strong>(Live)</a></li>

    <!--line-up item-->
    <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Bonaventure"><strong>Bonaventure</strong></a></li>

    <!--line-up item-->
    <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Ciel"><strong>Ciel</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is a long link which just not breaks and leave a lot of empty place:
[image] And I just want this text to break to 2 lines without `<br>` tag or something else, cause this layout must be responsive. Is there any way to make the link to be breakable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your elements `inline` and remove flexbox. You cannot achieve what you want by using flexbox since your elements are block level elements:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line-up {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e8c0a0;
}

.line-up__list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.line-up__item {
  display: inline;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 3px;
  line-height: 1.45;
}
.line-up__item:after {
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: 25px;
  content: '•';
  vertical-align:middle; /*added this too*/
}
.line-up__item:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}

a.line-up__link strong {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
  font-size: 19px;
}
a.line-up__link strong:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-up">

      <!--line up list-->
      <ul class="line-up__list">
        
        <!--line-up item-->
        <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Alva Noto Unieqav (Live)"><strong>Alva Noto Unieqav</strong>(Live)</a></li>
        
        <!--line-up item-->
        <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Anetha"><strong>Anetha</strong></a></li>
        
        <!--line-up item-->
        <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Antigone &amp; Shlømo présentent Luxor (Live) "><strong>Antigone &amp; Shlømo</strong>présentent<strong>Luxor</strong>(Live)</a></li>
        
        <!--line-up item-->
        <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Bonaventure"><strong>Bonaventure</strong></a></li>
        
        <!--line-up item-->
        <li class="line-up__item"><a class="line-up__link" href="line-up-details.html" title="Ciel"><strong>Ciel</strong></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```